# Query SQL Server resources per user/application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I understand there is no easy way to query resource usage (cpu time, disk reads/writes) per database, but is there a way to query that information per specific connection string or user?

I'm building an ASP.Net MVC3 application that uses Entity Framework to connect to a SQL Server database; I'm using the standard edition. I would like to know what my application costs on the database server.

Comment: And what **edition**??? SQL Server 2008 and up in the **Enterprise** edition has the [Resource Governor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx) which allows you to limit the resources (RAM, CPU etc.) that a particular application can use at any given time.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, it appears this project is not using 2008, but SQL Server 2005 Standard edition.

Answer (score 0):

Use sp_who or sp_who2 and get the result set into a table and use that table for your use.

Comment: Thanks, I looked these up and tried them out, but could you elaborate a bit please? The CPUTime and DiskIO columns in sp_who2 seem promising, but is there a way to get a total number over a certain time (or forever) without polling constantly?